# How to adjust thickness of lines in PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I took a screenshot of a design I like. I'd like to make the lines thicker in the design though. My first thought was to put it into photoshop and use the magic wand tool to remove the background. Not sure where to go from here. I would be open to using other software if that's easier.

Heres the scrn shot
[image]

**UPDATE**: I tried messing with `Filter -> Other -> Minimum` but this did not update the thickness of the lines evenly and also did something weird to the color. See image below.
[image]

Comment: You are better off starting a new document in Illustrator (or comparable vector based software). "Line thickness" is not something you can adjust with pixel based software, that's what vector art is for.

Comment: You could add a stroke layer style in Photoshop (after deleting the background like you have) not sure how good the results would be though. In all honesty you should just redraw the shapes. Illustrator would be best but you can do it in Photoshop. It shouldn't take more than a few minutes.

Comment: Could I convert to a vector than adjust line thickness?

Comment: @DanielKobe you can't exactly *convert* to vector. Illustrator has Image Trace which could work though.

Comment: Thoose shapes are too simple. Just re draw them in vector.

Comment: This is a very simple design and could be done quickly and easily using a few guides and some vector shapes. In fact it would probably be faster and easier than thickening the lines up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Photoshop:**
Select the area that you want, and make it grow to be thicker.

Looks like the best select option is Color Range.

1. Go to tab **Select > Color Range...** This will open the Color Range dialog box.
   Click anywhere on the area you wish to select, In this case the pink outline. Now the outline is selected. You can play with the fuzziness slider, if not enough of the outline is selected, or to much is selected.

   You can use any other selection tool if you are more comfortable with something else.
2. Go to **Select > Modify > Expand** . In the dialog box type in the number of pixels you want to be added to the selection. (I would try typing in 5 and seeing the result. You can always press CTRL+Z to undo the last step, or CTRL+SHIFT+Z to undo several last steps.)
3. Now click on the **Eyedropper** tool in the toolbox. Make sure that your Fill box, (situated on the bottom of the toolbox), is in the front, and not behind the Stroke box. Now click any where on the pink outline to choose the color.
4. Make a new layer, and press left ALT+DELETE. Now you have a new layer that contains a thicker outline in pink.

**In Illustrator:** I think the best option for this job would be a vector program. However it will take slightly more effort, and depending on why you need the design, you might be satisfied with using the previous solution.

1. Select the image. On the top ruler you should see a button **Image Trace**. Click on the small arrow near the button, and from the dropdown choose **3 Colors**. A Progress bar will show while the program converts the image to a group of vector shapes. Depending on your computer system this might take a while.
   If you are not satisfied with the result press CTRL+Z and try other image traces.
2. Click on the **Expand** button on the top ruler.
3. Select the image and Press CTRL+SHIFT+G to ungroup. Now click outside the image. Then select the black part of the image. Press DELETE. If there are any other black parts left, delete them as well. If you see that when you delete a black part, more pink is revealed underneath follow these steps:

   - Press CTRL+Z to return the black part to the image. Select both the pink and the black part.
   - Press CTRL+SHIFT+F9 and the **Pathfinder** window will open. Under **Shape Modes:** click on **Minus Front** button.
   - Repeat these steps with any other black parts that havethis issue.

[image]

4. Select your resulting pink shape. Make sure it is one shape. If it isn't, select all of the pink shapes, and in the **Pathfinder** window click on **Unite** button.
5. Click on the **Stroke** box on the bottom of the toolbar and color it in the same color as the pink shape. (There should be a small box underneath with the correct color, if not just make sure both the fill and the stroke of your shape are the same color.)

[image]

5. Now you can change the thickness of the stroke on the top toolbar, or the **Stroke** window.

   6. After you change the thickness of the stroke you can expand the entire shape+ stroke to one flat shape if you want. Just go to **Object > Expand Appearance** and in **Pathfinder** click on **Unite**.